# Cookies are not set under chrome dev-tools>Application>Cookies?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

Here is a screenshot of the application :

1: **We can see Set Cookie here**
[image: We can see Set Cookie here]

2: **We can see Cookie under response here**
[image: We can see Cookie here as well]

3: **Doesn't appear here**
[image]

Tried to find a lot of resources read things about CORS as well but still haven't been able to solve this issue.

**Update :**

After much discussions with my colleagues this issue couldn't be resolved, thus we have decided to change the code structure and the working of the application to go around this issue.

Comment: The cookie will only be visible for the domain: http://4bf9e0a0.ngrok.io

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate the answer below a bit? What do you mean by "only be visible for the domain: 4bf9e0a0.ngrok.io" & "write the cookie on your behalf for your domain http://samldemo.builtapp.io." ?

Comment: DO you know how to create a cookie server side? What programming language are you familiar with?

Comment: Node.js express framework. My colleague was working with it server side. The frontend is Angularjs.

Comment: SO you are able to publish content on  http://4bf9e0a0.ngrok.io/ ?

Comment: Yes. I can. But we haven't able to narrow down possible issue.

Comment: CAn you share the code from https://4bf9e0ae.ngrok.io/vl/application/users/saml/login_with_saml_token, the page "login_with_samll_token" will need to write the cookie

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157663/discussion-between-dai-bok-and-clive-mac).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is the endpoint http://4bf9e0a0.ngrok.io/ that generates the token cookie needs to write the cookie on your behalf for your domain http://samldemo.builtapp.io.

Ok in your saml auth service/ method on **ngrok.io** , when you write the cookie, set the domain similar to this:

```
setCookie('authtoken', 'bltd435345353453', { 
    domain: 'samldemo.builtapp.io', // The domain you to read the cookie on
    ... 
    ... 
    ... 
});
```

Some Auth/Token providers will provide an API to configure how the the token created and configured, for example setting up your domain, etc. This is only possible server side.